# Firebase Auth UI - "No eligible accounts can be found" error on sign out

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth UI (`com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2`) in my Android project and upon sign out I'm getting the following error:

```
01-30 22:08:39.730 8075-8075/com.ifeins.tenbis E/HomeActivity: signOut: Failed to sign out
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 1 out of 2 underlying tasks failed
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks$zzc.zzbjb(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks$zzc.onFailure(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh.run(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.execute(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzg.onComplete(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.setException(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setException(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaul.setResult(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauk.zze(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaur.onTransact(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: No eligible accounts can be found
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaul.setResult(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauk.zze(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaur.onTransact(Unknown Source) 
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

This is the code I'm using to perform the sign out:

```
private void signOut() {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .signOut(this)
            .addOnCompleteListener((task) -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    User.setCurrentUser(null);
                    showSignInDialog();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "signOut: Failed to sign out", task.getException());
                }
            });
}
```

This is the code I'm using to perform sign in (notice that I disable smart lock):

```
private void showSignInDialog() {
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Collections.singletonList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()
    );

    Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Is there something that I should do differently?

Comment: Make sure you've disabled automatic sign-in from Smart Lock, as instructed in [FirebaseUI's Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#sign-out)

Comment: I've disabled smart lock, both by calling the `setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)` method and by disabling it on the device itself, and I'm still getting the same error. I've updated the question description to include the sign in code as well.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues)